# Highlight similar character sequences between two Strings in two different cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have two Strings in different cells for example

> ***ADSGPINDTDANPR***
>
> RGTELDDGIQ***ADSGPINDTDANPR***Y VPGYY ESQSDDPHFHEK

Also character sequences can have gaps for similar sequences like RGX in following example

> ***LA***DNS T***FDDDLDDLTPSKMKPANFKGD***
>
> RS***LA*** ***FDDDLDDLTPS***RGX***KMKPANFKGD***YG

What I want to do is Highlight both the sequences as shown in above example in Bold And Italic but in color using VBA code.

### Edit :

As per the first answer of @milo5m

Sequence is highlighted as follows

> ***MNTVEEVDSEEDEE***SAP GSV GSMPSTG***SA***KYYTNRV***P***FDMI***A***
>
> EQP***MNTVEEVDSEEDEESAPA***

But desired result should be like this:

> ***MNTVEEVDSEEDEESAP*** GSV GSMPSTGSAKYYTNRVPFDMIA
>
> EQP***MNTVEEVDSEEDEESAP***A

### Edit 2 :

Currently answer of @milo5m highlights single characters as shown in below examples

> SK***P***ERYS***G***
>
> TA***PG***EQAQD

> S***KP***ERY***S***G
>
> AQD Q***K***LA***PS***E

In above examples no sequence should have been highlighted...

In other words, It should only highlight the Single characters when there is space before the Character, otherwise it should not highlight single characters between sequences.

Comment: The code I have only highlight the entire cell if Both the Strings are exactly the same... but I want to highlight only substrings that are common in both cells, not entire cell texts.

Comment: @AkhilHothi so you may have a look on the characters object of a range (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.characters)

Comment: @Shrotter I got you about how to color specific character, but How do I identify the similar sequences in the first place?

Comment: "LA" appears in all 4 strings -- why isn't "LA" highlighted?

Comment: It's similar to the basic problem in genetics where you are trying to find the best alignment between two sequences that may have insertions/deletions/mismatches but it's a fairly tough area e.g.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm

Comment: To a geneticist it would be annotated something like (I'm not an expert)  
                                        FDDDLDDLTPS---KMKPANFKGD

FDDDLDDLTPSRGXKMKPANFKGD

Comment: Please, show "the code you have". In this way we maybe better understand what is to be done and you prove that made some research by your one. So, don't you know the strings to be matched? Don't you know, at least, how many digits to be compared? So, should the code test any possible string, for all length possible, also inserting strings **like** "RGX", not knowing in which position? What this **like** should mean? That some other strings `like` "RGX" may be used? If so, don't you know what such strings **may exist** and a required algorithm have to test against **any possible string**?

Comment: @dcromley Thanks for your suggestion you are right I missed that part...

Comment: @AkhilHothi I've decided to give you an answer (fully optimized) against my better judgement :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really nice that we have these two as a reference
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0890540114000765
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Here is the main function which is returning all subsequences forming the LCS (if you join all the keys you get the LCS in reverse subsequence form).
Function returns a dictionary where keys are subsequences, and values are arrays with 2 elements (position of subsequence in seqA and position of subsequence in seqB).

```
Function GetLCSSubSequenceDict(seqA As String, seqB As String) As Object
    Set GetLCSSubSequenceDict = Nothing
    
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    n = Len(seqA)
    If n = 0 Then: Exit Function
    
    Dim j As Long, m As Long
    m = Len(seqB)
    If m = 0 Then: Exit Function
    
    Dim T() As Long
    ReDim T(0 To n, 0 To m)
    
    'Building up table
    For i = 1 To n
        For j = 1 To m
            If Mid$(seqA, i, 1) <> Mid$(seqB, j, 1) Then
                'bitwise max
                T(i, j) = T(i - 1, j) Xor ((T(i - 1, j) Xor T(i, j - 1)) And --(T(i - 1, j) < T(i, j - 1)))
            Else
                T(i, j) = T(i - 1, j - 1) + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    Dim subseqKey As String
    Dim subseqABDict As Object
    Set subseqABDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    'Backtracking and building up dict of subsequences
    'key = subsequence
    'value = array(starting pos of the key in seqA,starting pos of the key in seqB)
    i = n
    j = m
    Do While (i > 0 And j > 0)
        If Not Mid$(seqA, i, 1) <> Mid$(seqB, j, 1) Then
            subseqKey = Mid$(seqA, i, 1) & subseqKey
            i = i - 1
            j = j - 1
        ElseIf T(i - 1, j) > T(i, j - 1) Then
            If subseqKey <> vbNullString Then
                subseqABDict(subseqKey) = Array(i + 1, j + 1)
                subseqKey = vbNullString
            End If
            i = i - 1
        Else
            If subseqKey <> vbNullString Then
                subseqABDict(subseqKey) = Array(i + 1, j + 1)
                subseqKey = vbNullString
            End If
            j = j - 1
        End If
    Loop
    If subseqKey <> vbNullString Then
        subseqABDict(subseqKey) = Array(i + 1, j + 1)
    End If
    
    Set GetLCSSubSequenceDict = subseqABDict
    Set subseqABDict = Nothing
End Function
```

Time complexity of the function is O ( Len(seqA) * Len(seqB) ), for those who are interested.

Following is a show case of setting font properties on 2 ranges seqA and seqB.

```
Sub test()
    Dim seqA As Range
    Dim seqB As Range
    
    Set seqA = Range("A4")
    Set seqB = Range("B4")
    
    Dim fontColor As Long
    fontColor = RGB(84, 84, 84)
    
    Dim subseqKey As Variant
    Dim lcsSubSequenceDict As Object
    Set lcsSubSequenceDict = GetLCSSubSequenceDict(seqA.Value2, seqB.Value2)
    
    'gives subsequences in reversed order, since we used backtracking
    'MsgBox Join(lcsSubSequenceDict.keys())
    If lcsSubSequenceDict Is Nothing Then: Exit Sub
    For Each subseqKey In lcsSubSequenceDict
        With seqA.Characters(lcsSubSequenceDict(subseqKey)(0), Len(subseqKey)).Font
            .color = fontColor
            .Bold = True
            .Italic = True
        End With
        With seqB.Characters(lcsSubSequenceDict(subseqKey)(1), Len(subseqKey)).Font
            .color = fontColor
            .Bold = True
            .Italic = True
        End With
    Next subseqKey
    
    Set lcsSubSequenceDict = Nothing
    Set seqA = Nothing
    Set seqB = Nothing
End Sub
```

Edit:

(1) *Fixed - Backtracking showing positions in sequences further to the right for multiple candidates*

(2) *Main Function returns Collection now (was returning Dictionary)*

```
Function GetLCSSubSequenceCollection(seqA As String, seqB As String) As Collection
    Set GetLCSSubSequenceCollection = Nothing
    
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    n = Len(seqA)
    If n = 0 Then: Exit Function
    
    Dim j As Long, m As Long
    m = Len(seqB)
    If m = 0 Then: Exit Function
    
    Dim T() As Long
    ReDim T(0 To n, 0 To m)
    
    'Building up table
    For i = 1 To n
        For j = 1 To m
            If Mid$(seqA, i, 1) <> Mid$(seqB, j, 1) Then
                'bitwise max
                T(i, j) = T(i - 1, j) Xor ((T(i - 1, j) Xor T(i, j - 1)) And --(T(i - 1, j) < T(i, j - 1)))
            Else
                T(i, j) = T(i - 1, j - 1) + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    Dim subseqKey As String
    Dim subseqABCollection As Collection
    Set subseqABCollection = New Collection
    
    'Backtracking and building up collection of subsequences
    'value = array(subsequence, starting pos of the key in seqA,starting pos of the key in seqB)
    i = n
    j = m
    Do While (i > 0 And j > 0)
        If Not Mid$(seqA, i, 1) <> Mid$(seqB, j, 1) Then
            subseqKey = Mid$(seqA, i, 1) & subseqKey
            i = i - 1
            j = j - 1
        ElseIf T(i - 1, j) > T(i, j - 1) Then
            If subseqKey <> vbNullString Then
                subseqABCollection.Add Array(subseqKey, i + 1, j + 1)
                subseqKey = vbNullString
            End If
            i = i - 1
        Else
            If subseqKey <> vbNullString Then
                subseqABCollection.Add Array(subseqKey, i + 1, j + 1)
                subseqKey = vbNullString
            End If
            j = j - 1
        End If
    Loop
    If subseqKey <> vbNullString Then
        subseqABCollection.Add Array(subseqKey, i + 1, j + 1)
    End If
    
    If subseqABCollection.Count = 0 Then: Exit Function
    
    'fix backtracking showing positions in arrays further to the right for multiple candidates
    'using inStr to chack starting from prev position etc
    Dim prevSubseqPosA As Long, prevSubseqPosB As Long
    prevSubseqPosA = 1
    prevSubseqPosB = 1
    Set GetLCSSubSequenceCollection = New Collection
    For i = subseqABCollection.Count To 1 Step -1
        subseqKey = subseqABCollection.Item(i)(0)
        prevSubseqPosA = InStr(prevSubseqPosA, seqA, subseqKey)
        prevSubseqPosB = InStr(prevSubseqPosB, seqB, subseqKey)
        GetLCSSubSequenceCollection.Add Array(subseqKey, prevSubseqPosA, prevSubseqPosB)
        prevSubseqPosA = prevSubseqPosA + Len(subseqKey)
        prevSubseqPosB = prevSubseqPosB + Len(subseqKey)
    Next
    Set subseqABCollection = Nothing
End Function

Sub testCollection()
    Dim lcs As String
    Dim seqA As Range
    Dim seqB As Range
    
    Set seqA = Range("A4")
    Set seqB = Range("B4")
    
    Dim fontColor As Long
    fontColor = RGB(84, 84, 84)
    
    Dim lcsSubSequenceItem As Variant
    Dim lcsSubSequenceCollection As Collection
    Set lcsSubSequenceCollection = GetLCSSubSequenceCollection(seqA.Value2, seqB.Value2)
    
    If lcsSubSequenceCollection Is Nothing Then: Exit Sub
    For Each lcsSubSequenceItem In lcsSubSequenceCollection
        With seqA.Characters(lcsSubSequenceItem(1), Len(lcsSubSequenceItem(0))).Font
            .color = fontColor
            .Bold = True
            .Italic = True
        End With
        With seqB.Characters(lcsSubSequenceItem(2), Len(lcsSubSequenceItem(0))).Font
            .color = fontColor
            .Bold = True
            .Italic = True
        End With
        lcs = lcs & lcsSubSequenceItem(0)
    Next lcsSubSequenceItem
    
    MsgBox lcs & " [ LEN = " & Len(lcs) & " ]"
    
    Set lcsSubSequenceCollection = Nothing
    Set seqA = Nothing
    Set seqB = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello @ milo5m I am not able to check if the code is working or not because I am not using windows, I am using mac... I will soon check it on windows and reply accordingly.

Comment: I found out that I cannot use Dictionary object, and other alternatives are trickier...

Comment: Hi @ milo5m your answer is very close to what I want to achieve and thus I have accepted your answer, also It takes almost no time to perform my task, but There are cases where this algorithm is not accurate and I am editing the question so you can check and make changes in the code accordingly...

Comment: @AkhilHothi the reason is backtracking (when you have multiple candidates it picks the one further on the right of the sequence). I'll change things up a bit (today or  tomorrow) and make it work with collections which you can use.

Comment: Your code is almost working as desired, but it also highlights a single character, meaning no order is required to highlight... I have updated the question with Edit 2, also I believe this would be the last improvement needed in the code... Also now it is working on mac

Comment: @AkhilHothi Please come up with complete and precise spec of what is needed using relevant examples with edge cases. Current code does give proper LCS (by definition). And I'll see what I can do (today or tomorrow when I find some time) :)

Answer (score 2):

Tough challenge, and I'm not sure if it's that feasible with Excel alone. Assuming that:

- You will not allow the 1st entry to have gaps;
- You allow for 0+ gaps in between in the 2nd entry;
- You are looking for the longest match between both entries;
- You have ms365;

You may try the below answer that I based of on a formula first, see the below screenshot:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=LET(x,SCAN(,UNIQUE(TOCOL(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),SEQUENCE(1,LEN(A1))))),LAMBDA(a,b,TEXTJOIN("*",,MID(b,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(b)),1)))),y,SEARCH(x,B1),z,SORTBY(HSTACK(x,y),LEN(x)*(ISNUMBER(y)),-1),SUBSTITUTE(TAKE(FILTER(z,ISNUMBER(INDEX(z,,2))),1,1),"*",))
```

The above will identify the longest substring that has a match with 0+ gaps in between. This is going to be the input to the below macro:

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, x As Long, y As Long, z As Long, a As Long, arr As Variant, s As String

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
arr = ws.Range("A1:C" & lr)

For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    s = arr(x, 3)
    
    'Format column A:A
    ws.Cells(x, 1).Characters(InStr(1, ws.Cells(x, 1).Value, s), Len(s)).Font.Bold = True
    ws.Cells(x, 1).Characters(InStr(1, ws.Cells(x, 1).Value, s), Len(s)).Font.Italic = True
    
    'Format column B:B
    z = 0
    For y = 1 To Len(s)
        z = InStr(z + 1, ws.Cells(x, 2).Value, Mid(s, y, 1))
        ws.Cells(x, 2).Characters(z, 1).Font.Bold = True
        ws.Cells(x, 2).Characters(z, 1).Font.Italic = True
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

The results look like:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't do exactly what I asked but very close to what I wanted... Thanks I have upvoted your answer :)

Comment: @AkhilHothi you are welcome. Can you elaborate a bit more on what is not as intended? Note that I had to make some assumptions at the top of the answer.

Comment: First of all I don't have 365 subscription and that's why I can use your formula, I would be great you have put a vba code in your answer that identify similar portions in sequences. Also I wanted to highlight similarities with color not bold italic, but that is not my first concern.

Comment: Yeah I am sure someone smart can figure out a VBA equivalent. About the formatting: you could color a character, but 'highlight' a single character with a background fill is not possible unless you fill the entire cell AFAIK.

Comment: I don't have 365 subscription but I have excel, and when I put the formula it gives error that function is invalid. I guess you know the reason for that...

Comment: I see you have now made the answer obsolete by altering the question.